# Missing table Headers in CSS Responsive Table

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am using below-mentioned CSS code to display responsive table in WordPress. But the displayed responsive table is a header. Here I am using custom code to generate a table. Can anyone help me?

**HTML**

```
$menu .= '<table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Price</th></tr></thead>';
            while ( have_rows('sections_items') ) : the_row();
                    // Your loop code
                    $menu .= '<tr><td>'.get_sub_field('dish_names').'</td><td>'.get_sub_field('dish_description').'</td><td>$ '.get_sub_field('dish_price').'</td></tr>';
           endwhile;
$menu .= '</table> '
```

**css**

```
table {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }
    table caption {
      font-size: 1.5em;
      margin: .5em 0 .75em;
    }
    table tr {
      background: #f8f8f8;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      padding: .35em;
    }
    table th,
    table td {
      padding: .625em;
      text-align: center;
    }
    table th {
      font-size: .85em;
      letter-spacing: .1em;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      table {
        border: 0;
      }
      table caption {
        font-size: 1.3em;
      }
      table thead {
        border: none;
        clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
        height: 1px;
        margin: -1px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 1px;
      }
      table tr {
        border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: .625em;
      }
      table td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        display: block;
        font-size: .8em;
        text-align: right;
      }
      table td:before {
        /*
        * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
        content: attr(aria-label);
        */
        content: attr(data-label);
        float: left;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
      table td:last-child {
        border-bottom: 0;
      }
    }
```

Comment: a semi-colon is missing `$menu .= '</table> '`

Comment: no it displayed table but headers are missing.

Comment: what's the source of the displayed page?